# Add row to WinForms DataGridView working with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6

i have a database structure like this:

### Employees

Id : int (Primary Key),
Forename : varchar,
Surname : varchar,
Department : int (Foreign Key)

### Departments

Id : int (Primary Key),
Department : varchar

So i have a relation from Employees.Department to Departments.Id.

Now i want to display all database rows in the WinForms DataGridView.

My code looks like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EntityFramework ef = new EntityFramework();
    var query = ((from contact in ef.Mitarbeiter.Select(
       x => new { Id = x.Id, Forename = x.Forename, Surname = x.Surname, Department = x.Departments.Department })
                  select contact).ToList());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
}
```

So i created an anonymous Type for the query. I can't create an Employee because of the departments foreign key.

But now I have my main problem:

How can i now for example add a new Row to the DataGrid or edit some cells?

What is the best practice for working with an Entity Framework and a DataGridView with Foreign Keys?

Comment: have you tried anything to solve your main problem (except posting it to SO)? i can estimate an amount of work required and the question is really broad

Comment: Yes i have tried to add a new row or double click in a cell but nothing happend